# Graduating with a PhD in May, should I take a good offer in an undesired location?

Tags: job-search, stem

I'm not sure if this is the correct StackExchange site to post this on, but I did not see one that was a closer fit.

I'm graduating with my Ph.D. in Mechanical Engineering from a mid-tier program in the US in May. I am targeting industry as my prefered career path and was advised to start applying to jobs a few months ago.

I've had phone screenings with a few companies that have told me to get back in contact in the new year. However, I got a good offer (pay/benefits/semi-interesting work) from one company that's far away from my hometown (which I would prefer to be near).

So after all this set-up I have two questions

1. Does anyone have resources about the pay for a newly minted ME PhD? I found a report from the [ASME/ASCE from 2012](https://www.asme.org/getmedia/788e990f-99f5-4062-801c-d2ef0586b52d/32673_Engineering_Income_Salary_Survey.aspx) (Exhibit 11) that lists some statistics. But I was hoping for something more up to date.
2. Should I be worried that I'm not getting more interviews, or is this simply a product of May being relatively far out for companies to hire?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you care about your career, be prepared to move to wherever you find the best opportunity.

Comment: 100%...He must weigh up his priorities.